# Django - Unable to Display Values on Page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-urls

I am unable to display values from DB on home page. I can't figure out what I've done wrong. Following is my html

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" async></script>
    </head>

    <div class="container">
        {% for manhour in manhours %}
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ manhour.station }}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ manhour.date|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'manhour-detail' manhour.id %}">{{ manhour.station }}</a></h2>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="user_panel">
                <a href="/logout">logout</a>
    </div>
    <div class="user_panel">
                <a href="/manhour/new">Upload</a>
    </div>

</html>
```

**view.py**

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from .form import InputForm
from manhour.models import ManHour 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.urls import reverse


def login_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                return redirect('manhour-home')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request = request,
                    template_name = "manhour/login.html",
                    context={"form":form})


class PostListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = ManHour
    template_name = 'manhour/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'manhour'
    # ordering = ['-date']


class PostDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = ManHour
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
# from manhour.views import login_request
from manhour.views import (
    PostListView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    login_request
)
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', login_request, name='login'),
    path('', login_request, name='login'),
    path('manhour/', PostListView.as_view(), name='manhour-home'),
    path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('manhour/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='manhour-create'),
    path('manhour/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='manhour-detail'),
    path('manhour/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='manhour-update'),
]
```

Can anyone identify why I can't list all values on my `manhour-home` page? On home page I can see `logout` and `upload` button which is working fine. But I am unable to view all the objects from database on home page.

**Update**
I've added following into `views.py`

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'manhour': ManHour.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'manhour/home.html', context)
```

Comment: Your update is not going to work, because your home page is linked to PostListView.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined what needs to be displayed in the view. You can either define a **queryset** attribute for the view, or define **get_queryset()** method.

Comment: I've added what needs to be displayed see update. Still I can't see anything on home page.

Comment: @Lopez: are you logged in when trying to access the home page? do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your context object name is wrong, in views you are using "manhour" and in your home template you are using "manhours".

So, I think this should fix it.

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'manhours': ManHour.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'manhour/home.html', context)
```